# strtok Unhandled exception;Access violation writing location

Tags: c, runtime-error, strtok, string-literals, unhandled

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>

char *matrix[10][10];
int main(void) {
    int i;
    char *list[4];
    char *words[20] = {
        " c a t ", " c a r ", " b e a r ", " s h i p ",
        " m o u s e ", " b e a t l e ", " c o a t ", " n e s t ",
        " i c e ", " s u g a r ", " b a c o n ", " f r o w n ",
        " s m i l e ", " d e a d ", " f e a t h e r ", " g o a t ",
        " h e n "," j e l l y "," k o a l a "," l i p s "
    };

    int length;
    int num;
    int k;
    int m;
    char otherString=0;
    char *c;
    int j;
    int s;
    int r;
    char test[10];
    char *token;
    const char *search = " ";
    char *empty = "";
    int size;
    int ans;
    int x;
    int y;
    int pos;
    int pos2;
    int randRow;
    int randColumn;
    int chosen[10];
    int random;
    int d;
    int ROWS = 10;      // number of rows
    int COLUMNS = 10;      // number of columns

    printf("\tA\tB\tC\tD\tE\tF\tG\tH\tI\tJ\n");
    srand(time(NULL));

    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        printf( "\n" );
        d = 0;
        do {
            random = (rand() % 20);
            list[i] = words[random];
            d = 0;
            for (j = 0; j < i; j++) {
                if (strcmp(words[random], list[j]) == 0)
                    d = 1;
            }
        } while (d);
    }

    token = strtok((words[random]), search); 

    while (token != NULL) {
        length = strlen(words[random]);
        for (k = 0; k < length; k++) {
            matrix[i][k] = token;
            token = strtok(NULL, search); 
            matrix [i][k] = token;
        }
    }
    for (r = 0; r < 10; r++) {
        printf("\n");   
        for (s = 0; s < 10; s++) {
            //ans = strlen(matrix[r][s]);
            /* if (ans == 0) {
                c = 'A' + (rand() % 26);
                matrix[r][s] = c;
            }*/
            printf("\t%s", matrix[r][s]);
        }
    }
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

> Basically this program generates 4 random words which cannot be
>   duplicate
>       `strtok` is used to slip the words so that they 
>       can be entered char by char into matrix. finally any 
>       null chars in the matrix will be replaced with random 
>       characters. 
>       however `strtok` is generating runtime error and I am not
>        sure how to check for a null element ?

Comment: `strtok` change the string, but you can not string literals to change.

Comment: so how do i fix the error ?

Comment: what about  how to check for a null element ?

Comment: Did the cat walk randomly on your space bar?

Answer (score 1):

In this statement

```
token = strtok((words[random]),search);
```

function `strtok` tries to change a string literal addressed by the array element `words[random]`.

String literals are immutable in C. Any attempt to change a string literal results in undefined behaviour.

Instead of the array of pointers to string literals

```
 char *words[20]={" c a t "," c a r "," b e a r "," s h i p "," m o u s e "," b e a t l e "," c o a t "," n e s t "," i c e "," s u g a r "," b a c o n "," f r o w n "," s m i l e "," d e a d "," f e a t h e r "," g o a t "," h e n "," j e l l y "," k o a l a "," l i p s "};
```

you should define a two dimensional character array initialized by the string literals. For example

```
 char words[20][20]={" c a t "," c a r "," b e a r "," s h i p "," m o u s e "," b e a t l e "," c o a t "," n e s t "," i c e "," s u g a r "," b a c o n "," f r o w n "," s m i l e "," d e a d "," f e a t h e r "," g o a t "," h e n "," j e l l y "," k o a l a "," l i p s "};
```

Comment: this produces no errors however, still not the correct outcome?

Comment: @chris Correct the error with the array and ask a new question. It is not a good idea when the content of a question is changed. This confuses readers.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
>   token = strtok((words[random]),search); 
>
>   while(token!=NULL) 
>    {
>     length=strlen(words[random]);
>
>     for( k=0;k<length;k++){
>
>       matrix [i][k]=token;
>
>         token = strtok(NULL, search); 
>
>
>           matrix [i][k]=token;
>
>     } 
>   }
> ```

This is messed and not what you intend. Change it to something straight, e. g.:

```
    for (k = 0, c = words[random]; token = strtok(c, search); c = NULL, ++k)
        matrix[i][k] = token;
```